# Angular 7 map form data to API model

Tags: angular, typescript, automapper, asp.net-core-webapi, angular7

I have an Angular (using the latest version of Angular 7) formgroup with nested form groups:

```
this.form = this._formBuilder.group({
    person: this._formBuilder.group({
        name: [''. Validators.required],
        firstName: [''. Validators.required],
        birthDate: [new Date()]
    }),
    request: this._formBuilder.group({
        title: [''. Validators.required],
        startDate: [new Date()],
        endDate: [new Date()],
    }),
});
```

This needs to be mapped to an API POST model that has a different structure:

```
interface ApiData {
    personName: string;
    personFirstName: string;
    personBirthDate: Date;
    requestTitle: string;
    requestStartDate: Date;
    requestEndDate: Date;
}
```

Currently I have a _patchForm method that is called on init if the form is used as edit form (if an id is in the route) to transform the API data to the form model:
On form submit I transform the form model to the API data.

```
let entity: ApiData = {};
entity.personName = this.form.get('person').get('name').value;
entity.personFirstName = this.form.get('person').get('firstName').value;
...
this._http.post(apiUrl, entity).subscribe( ... )
```

In C# I use Automapper for this, but because automapper-ts is not written for Angular, I’m not sure that this will work with the FormGroup model.

Is this possible or is there another, more Angular way to solve this? I’m doing this type of convertion on forms all over my app.

Comment: Well, you could simply use the same structure in your FormGroup as the structure expected by the API. Otherwise, yes, you need to do what you're doing. It could be made simpler by using `this.form.value.person.name`.

Comment: I cant use the same structure in my formgroup, because each nested formgroup is a separate component that is combined on nginit of the main form component. I’m using AoT and Universal, so I think I have to get them by string name.

Comment: Nice idea - to create form mapper for Angular. It would be interesting to takd a look ar c# code with suto-mapper